# pandas Series determine which key(s) does not exist in a dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
currency    value
USD         1.0
EUR         2.0
RMB         3.0
```

and I get a `dict` for containing exchange rates,

```
rates = {'GBP': 0.76, 'USD': 1.0, 'CNY': 6.6}
```

when I do

```
df['value'].div(df['currency'].map(rates))
```

how do I know/get which value in `currency` did not get map to `rates`, like a `KeyError`, I tried

```
try:
    df['amount'] = df.['value'].div(df['currency'].map(rates))
except KeyError as e:
    print('Key {} does not exist in the exchange rates dictionary'.format(e.args[0]))
```

but no errors were thrown. I am wondering how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code working and if no key in dict get `NaN`s in column `value`.

So need all `currency` with `NaN`s after `map`:

```
a = df['value'].div(df['currency'].map(rates))

b = df.loc[a.isnull(), 'currency']
print (b)
1    EUR
2    RMB
Name: currency, dtype: object
```